# I can't install python with home-brew, because of no bottle available

Tags: python, homebrew

As the question title says, facing the below error. using Mac.

how can I install python with homebrew again not with building from source?

Even though I deleted python@3.8 from homebrew, when I type `which python3` there's still python3 here `/usr/local/bin/python3`. is this meaning that I haven't used python installed from homebrew?.

```
python@3.8: no bottle available!
You can try to install from source with e.g.
  brew install --build-from-source python@3.8
Please note building from source is unsupported. You will encounter build
failures with some formulae. If you experience any issues please create pull
requests instead of asking for help on Homebrew's GitHub, Twitter or any other
official channels.
```

Comment: can you also paste `brew config` for me?

Comment: What version of macOS?

Comment: @CrazyChucky I had Big Sur, but I downgraded it to Catalina just a short while ago and downloaded pyenv to control python versions, I should have known this earlier, it's convenient.

Comment: ended up downgrading to Catalina OS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

homebrew only supports the latest three macOS (which are mojave, catalina, and big_sur), the bottles are listed in [here](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/python@3.8.rb#L13-L18). You can also see Apple Silicon version there as well.

So if you are on the latest homebrew-core, you can only install from bottles with those three OSX.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue. I ran `xcode-select --install`. This installed the CLT for my mac. Then I was able to install python3 by running `xcode-select --install`